# PhpStorm and Yii, auto complete own module

Tags: autocomplete, yii, phpstorm

I configured PhpStorm to the following: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/92/configuring-phpstorm-ide-for-yii/

Auto completes works now for me. But when I write my own components I am not able to get the methods, vars and attributes.

**What I did:**

In CApplication.php I added:

```
@property mixed testComponent
```

In myComponent.php I added:

```
/* @property string $theVar
 * @method thefunction
 */
```

Comment: Well .. lets try: **1)** instead of `mixed testComponent` put correct class instead of `mixed` **2)** (it can be typo or something different, but) PHPDoc comments have 2 asterisks not 1: `/**` **3)** Use proper `@method` syntax: http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/tags/method.html

Comment: Following previous comment, when you put double '*', you'll see the whole @var tag in bold (just to verify)